# Mysql: showing order number per customer for each order

Tags: mysql

I have a table listing order_id, order_date and user_id.

I have no issue retrieving how many orders each customer has made and displaying that next to the order_id. However, what I've been trying unsuccessfully is to display next to each order_id which the n-th order value for each individual customer.

```
SELECT order.id,
       order.user_id,
       date(from_unixtime(order.created_date))
       COUNT(order2.id)
FROM order order
JOIN order order2
           ON order2.user_id = order.user_id
AND order2.created_date <= order.created_date
GROUP
BY order.user_id,
   date(from_unixtime(order.created_date)),
   order.id
ORDER
BY order.user_id,
   date(from_unixtime(order.created_date)),
   order.id;
```

This gives me just the total numbers of orders per user for each of his orders rather than the n-th value.

The result should like something like this:

```
created_date  order_id  user_id  order_number
2016-11-21     234        12       2
2016-10-15     123        16       1
2016-10-03     234        12       1
```

many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please post the table structure? What does `n-th order value` mean?

Comment: For each user count his how many-ieth order it is in ascending order. If a user has 3 orders, the earliest order would return 1, the second order return 2, the third order return 3.

Comment: use AND order2.id <= order.id instead of created_date

Comment: @89ZiNws You have provided expected result. Kindly provide the sample data of table.

Comment: @Viki888 table sample is the same as the result minus the order_number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can add another one join and change the first a bit:

```
SELECT order.id,
       order.user_id,
       date(from_unixtime(order.created_date))
       COUNT(distinct order3.id) - COUNT(distinct order2.id)
FROM order order
JOIN order order2
           ON order2.user_id = order.user_id
AND order2.created_date > order.created_date
JOIN order order3
           ON order2.user_id = order.user_id
GROUP
BY order.user_id,
   date(from_unixtime(order.created_date)),
   order.id
ORDER
BY order.user_id,
   date(from_unixtime(order.created_date)),
   order.id;
```

Comment: but want to warn you, join tables on self is a very bad approach, you can use it as a workaround, quick-fix, or on really small tables